# Reactjs getting event from store with fluxible

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactjs-flux, fluxible

Hi I m actually trying to developp a little applications using flux, reactjs and fluxible and I m facing a problem when dealing with stores.

In fact, I can send information to my store through actions, but I dont know how to receive the result of this.emitChange in stores inside of my component to refresh the screen.

What should I put in my component to refresh my list ?

Here's my component :

```
import React from 'react';

class Client extends React.Component {

    constructor (props) {
      super(props);
      this.myListView = [];
    }

    add(e){
      this.context.executeAction(function (actionContext, payload, done) {
          actionContext.dispatch('ADD_ITEM', {name:'toto'});
      });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h2>Client</h2>
                <p>List of all the clients</p>
                <button onClick={this.add.bind(this)}>Click Me</button>
                <ul>
                    {this.myListView.map(function(title) {
                      return <li key={name}>{name}</li>;
                    })}
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
}


Client.contextTypes = {
    executeAction: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

export default Client;
```

Here's my store

```
import BaseStore from 'fluxible/addons/BaseStore';

class ListStore extends BaseStore {

  constructor(dispatcher) {
      super(dispatcher);
      this.listOfClient = [];
    }

  dehydrate() {
      return {
          listOfClient: this.listOfClient
      };
  }

  rehydrate(state) {
      this.listOfClient = state.listOfClient;
  }


  addItem(item){
    this.listOfClient.push(item);
    this.emitChange();
  }

}

ListStore.storeName = 'ListStore';
ListStore.handlers = {
    'ADD_ITEM': 'addItem'
};

export default ListStore;
```

**UPDATE**

this.setState is not well applied

```
_onStoreChange() {
      console.log(this.getStoreState()) // gives me the good list
      this.setState(this.getStoreState()); // doesn't update the list, this.myListView gives [] always
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to put `myListView` into the component's state and populate it from the store on instantiation.

So your component will end up something like:

```
import ListStore from '../stores/ListStore';
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    static contextTypes = {
        getStore: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired,
        executeAction: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
    }

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = this.getStoreState();
        this.boundChangeListener = this._onStoreChange.bind(this);
    }
    getStoreState () {
        return {
            myListView: this.context.getStore(ListStore).getItems()
        }
    }
    componentDidMount () {
        this.context.getStore(ListStore).addChangeListener(this.boundChangeListener);
    }
    componentWillUnmount () {
        this.context.getStore(ListStore).removeChangeListener(this.boundChangeListener);
    }
    _onStoreChange () {
        this.setState(this.getStoreState());
    }
    add(e){
      this.context.executeAction(function (actionContext, payload, done) {
          actionContext.dispatch('ADD_ITEM', {name:'toto'});
       });
    }
    render () {
    return (
        <div>
            <h2>Client</h2>
            <p>List of all the clients</p>
            <button onClick={this.add.bind(this)}>Click Me</button>
            <ul>
                {this.state.myListView.map(function(title) {
                  return <li key={name}>{name}</li>;
                })}
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
    }
}
```

This way you'll listen to changes and trigger `setState` on the component, causing a re-render.

### Update to the `add` method

In the original code above, I'm not sure the way the action is executed on click is correct. Perhaps try:

```
add(e) {
    this.context.executeAction(function(actionContext, payload, done) {
        actionContext.dispatch('ADD_ITEM', payload);
        done();
    }, {name: 'toto'});
}
```

Comment: This seems to work but I ve got an undefined on this.getStoreState... :O

Comment: Thank you for your help, React and flux are not that easy to learn... I m having another problem _onStoreChange() {
      this.setState(this.getStoreState());
    } doesn't refresh the myListView. It's really hard to understand why at the first time. Thanks for your help

Comment: I think there's some issues with your `add` function, I'll add another update

Comment: I have updated my question because my problem is not there :-)

Comment: You need to pull your data from `this.state` so `this.state.myListView`

Comment: This is so weird x_x I got a Cannot read property 'getStore' of undefined

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88761/discussion-between-ian-thomas-and-skahrz).